# how to make data from a html form go into a api link url using an api url

Tags: javascript, html, css

create an a form with online one input of email and a submit button.
make sure the data of the form goes to this url https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/20469527/2s83tCKYGN

i tried and created a html form and used css to beautify it and but havent been able to link the data in the form to the api url given

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.getElementById("form").onsubmit = e=>e.preventDefault()
```

```html
<form id="form" action="https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/20469527/2s83tCKYGN" method="post"><input type="email" name="email"
        ><input type="submit" value="Submit"></form>
```